# Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, injeção-de-dependência, ddd, ninject

Estou construindo uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC5 usando DDD e separei a minha camada de IoC da minha aplicação web.
Nos meus controllers eu tenho construtores com parâmetro para receber uma instancia da minha classe de serviços.
Estou usando Ninject, nisso criei uma classe que extende IDependencyResolver, assim no meu Global.asax consigo chamar o seguinte código:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new App.Infra.Ioc.MyDependencyResolver());
```

Dentro da classe MyDependencyResolver eu faço os binds das minhas dependências.

O problema é que quando chamo minha action, por exemplo `Clientes/Index` o sistema me retorna o erro:

```
Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto.
[MissingMethodException: Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +232
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +110
```

Eu sei que este erro ocorre porque não está sendo mapeada a minha dependência, mas deveria funcionar, porque no Global.asax eu passo pro DependencyResolver a minha injeção de dependência.

Eu já implementei em outro projeto usando a NinjectWebCommon, porém, esta ficava dentro do projeto Asp.Net MVC. O que eu quero é implementar isso em um projeto fora.

Como faço isso?

Comment: Seria interessante colocar o código de seu Controller na pergunta (Construtor, Action ...).

Comment: Na verdade o erro diz que está tentando criar uma classe (que não sabemos qual é) utilizando um construtor vazio. Se a classe for sua, implementando um construtor vazio já resolve **este** erro em específico.

Comment: Já pensou em colocar um método construtor sem parâmetros na classe? `public IoC(){}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **Solução**

Como o @iuristona havia falado, o problema era que o meu container IoC não estava conseguindo resolver a dependência do construtor da minha Controller.

Investigando eu descobri o problema, segue o código do módulo Ninject:

```
public class ModuloDomainCommon : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind(typeof(IServiceBase<>)).To(typeof(ServiceBase<>));
            Bind<ILoginService>().To<LoginService>();

            Bind(typeof(IRepositoryBase<>)).To(typeof(RepositoryBase<>));
            Bind<ILoginRepository>().To<LoginRepository>();

        }
    }
```

Ocorria que eu não tinha colocado o `typeof` nas minhas dependências genéricas como `IServiceBase` e `IRepositoryBase`. Se não fizer isso o compilador não consegue encontrar o tipo das classes genéricas e consequentemente o container IoC não consegue resolver a dependência. 
Depois de adicionar o `typeof` fiz o seguinte:

**Classe IoC**

Aqui é aonde faço a leitura dos módulos Ninject.

```
public class IoC
    {
        public IoC()
        {
            Kernel = new StandardKernel(
                new ModuloDomainCommon();

            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new NinjectServiceLocator(Kernel));
        }

        public IKernel Kernel { get; private set; }
    }
```

**Classe MyDependencyResolver**

Aqui é a minha classe que estende a IDependencyResolver, e aonde chamo a classe IoC que contém os módulos Ninject.

```
public class MyDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IKernel _kernel;
        public MyDependencyResolver()
        {
            var ioc = new IoC();
            _kernel = ioc.Kernel;
        }

    #region IDependencyResolver Members
        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
        }
    #endregion
}
```

**Global.asax**

Aqui é a chamada do SetResolver do DependencyResolver para a minha classe MyDependencyResolver que está em um projeto separado. 
Assim consegui isolar a minha camada de injeção de dependência em um projeto de infraestrutura separado da minha camada de apresentação.

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new MyApp.Infraestrutura.IoC.MyDependencyResolver());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pois é, esse erro ocorre porque o seu container IoC não está conseguindo resolver a dependência no construtor do seu `Controller`, enquanto o MVC não encontra uma versão do construtor sem parâmetros.

Não sei se você vai conseguir implementar seu IoC pro MVC em um projeto externo, já que precisa implementar a interface `IDependencyResolver` que faz parte do `System.Web.Mvc`.

Segue a minha versão usando [ninject](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject) "puro":

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private IKernel _kernel;

        public NinjectDependencyResolver()
        {
            _kernel = new StandardKernel();

            RegisterServices(_kernel);
        }

        public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
        {
            _kernel = kernel;
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
        }

        public static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {    

            // configure aqui seus serviços
            // kernel.Bind<InterfaceType>().To<ConcreteType>();
            kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<MyDbContext>();//.WithConstructorArgument("nameOrConnectionString", "CpsConnectionString");
        }
    }
```

Comment: consegue achar. Sua resposta me ajudou, pois foi ai que lembrei que o eror estava ocorrendo porque não estava conseguindo resolver a dependência. Postei a solução completa na resposta abaixo.