# IOC - Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

Estou fazendo um projeto e eles está separado em camadas, posso chamar  de DDD.
Porém estou com o seguinte erro:

**Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto.**

Estou usando Ioc, segue abaixo como estou fazendo:

```
public class NinjectWebCommon
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    public static void Start()
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);


    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel));
            RegisterServices(kernel);
              return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind(typeof(IAppServiceBase<>)).To(typeof(AppServiceBase<>));
        kernel.Bind<IConhecimentoAppService>().To<ConhecimentoAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IDadosBancariosAppService>().To<DadosBancariosAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IDisponibilidadeAppService>().To<DisponibilidadeAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IHorarioAppService>().To<HorarioAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IPessoaAppService>().To<PessoaAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IPessoaConhecimentoAppService>().To<PessoaConhecimentoAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IPessoaDisponibilidadeAppService>().To<PessoaDisponibilidadeAppService>();
        kernel.Bind<IPessoaHorarioAppService>().To<PessoaHorarioAppService>();



        kernel.Bind(typeof(IServiceBase<>)).To(typeof(ServiceBase<>));
        kernel.Bind<IConhecimentoService>().To<ConhecimentoService>();
        kernel.Bind<IDadosBancariosService>().To<DadosBancariosService>();
        kernel.Bind<IDisponibilidadeService>().To<DisponibilidadeService>();
        kernel.Bind<IHorarioService>().To<HorarioService>();
        kernel.Bind<IPessoaService>().To<PessoaService>();
        kernel.Bind<IPessoaConhecimentoService>().To<PessoaConhecimentoService>();
        kernel.Bind<IPessoaDisponibilidadeService>().To<PessoaDisponibilidadeService>();
        kernel.Bind<IPessoaHorarioService>().To<PessoaHorarioService>();


        kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepositoryBase<>)).To(typeof(RespositoryBase<>));
        kernel.Bind<IConhecimentoRepository>().To<ConhecimentoRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IDadosBancariosRepository>().To<DadosBancariosRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IDisponibilidadeRepository>().To<DisponibilidadeRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IHorarioRepository>().To<HorarioRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IPessoaRepository>().To<PessoaRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IPessoaConhecimentoRepository>().To<PessoaConhecimentoRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IPessoaDisponibilidadeRepository>().To<PessoaDisponibilidadeRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IPessoaHorarioRepository>().To<PessoaHorarioRepository>();
    }
}
```

**Controller está feita assim:**

```
public class PessoaController : Controller
{
    private readonly IPessoaAppService _pessoaApp;
    private readonly IConhecimentoAppService _conhecimentoApp;



    public PessoaController(IPessoaAppService pessoaApp, IConhecimentoAppService conhecimentoApp)
    {
        _pessoaApp = pessoaApp;
        _conhecimentoApp = conhecimentoApp;

    }

 // GET Pessoa/GetPessoa
    public JsonResult GetPessoa()
    {
        try
        {

           var pessoaViewModel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Pessoa>, IEnumerable<PessoaViewModel>>(_pessoaApp.GetAll());

            List<PessoaViewModel> pessoas = pessoaViewModel.ToList();

            return Json(pessoas, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47947/nenhum-construtor-sem-par%c3%a2metros-foi-definido-para-este-objeto)

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia Tatiane.

Creio que o erro esta ocorrendo no momento em que vc esta resolvendo o objeto PessoaController, correto?

Se for este o caso, o que esta ocorrendo é que o a classe PessoaController possui apenas um construtor, e o mesmo possui parâmetros (IPessoaAppService pessoaApp, IConhecimentoAppService conhecimentoApp). Porém, no momento em que o ninject esta criando uma nova instancia desse objeto (PessoaController) ele não sabe quais valores passar para o construtor, então ele busca um construtor sem parâmetros e este não existe no objeto.

Para resolver isso existe duas formas:

1. Criar um construtor sem parâmetros
2. informar ao ninject quais parâmetros devem ser passados para o construtor. Mais informações nesse [post][1]